# NPM warnings when installing @nuxtjs/apollo

Tags: npm, command-line, graphql, nuxt.js, apollo

I'm not super confident in terminals/CMD and I'm trying to install Nuxt's Apollo module after setting up a Nuxt project via `npx create-nuxt-app`. When I do, via `npm install @nuxtjs/apollo@latest` in my Nuxt directory, I get the following gumf:

```
npm WARN tailwindcss@2.2.2 requires a peer of autoprefixer@^10.0.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN vue-cli-plugin-apollo@0.22.2 requires a peer of @vue/cli-shared-utils@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN apollo-link-persisted-queries@0.2.2 requires a peer of graphql@^0.11.0 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 || ^14.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ts-node@8.10.2 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @apollographql/graphql-language-service-interface@2.0.2 requires a peer of graphql@^0.10.0 || ^0.11.0 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 || ^14.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @apollographql/graphql-language-service-utils@2.0.2 requires a peer of graphql@^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 || ^14.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @apollographql/graphql-language-service-types@2.0.2 requires a peer of graphql@^0.10.0 || ^0.11.0 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 || ^14.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @apollographql/graphql-language-service-parser@2.0.2 requires a peer of graphql@^0.10.0 || ^0.11.0 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 || ^14.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

I've no idea if this is significant. It then invites me to run `npm audit fix`, which I did, and it then tells me it was able to fix 0 of 15 issues and that they need manually fixing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are:

- not confident with CLI commands
- using NPM and not yarn (double check that you don't have any `yarn.lock` in your project)
- don't have any **critical** issues

You can then proceed safely. Here, you only do have warning and it's pretty the daily routine in the JS world. Nothing to really worry about.

Also, if you are able to run the project without any error in the console (browser and CLI), you're good to go!

Comment: Thank you. Yes I'm using NPM over Yarn. It's just a bit daunting when you do what the tutorial says, and you're met with a wall of NPM warnings!

Comment: Yeah, the JS ecosystem moves quickly hence all the warnings. Can be a bit surprising at first indeed.